# Gulp: Uglifying Bootstrap 4 js files

Tags: javascript, gulp, bootstrap-4

Since the latest changes to the Bootstrap 4 Alpha, I can't minify the core .js files with my current Gulp task. I get the error: "GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript".

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43842786/how-to-uglify-bootstrap-4-alpha-selected-files-uncaught-referenceerror-exports), I added `gulp-babel` and `gulp-webpack` but it's not working.

What am I missing?

Excerp of gulp.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var webpack = require('gulp-webpack');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');

// List of .js files to concatenate
var js = {
    jsSrc: [
        paths.src + "/js/alert.js",
        paths.src + "/js/button.js",
        paths.src + "/js/collapse.js",
        paths.src + "/js/modal.js",
        paths.src + "/js/util.js",
        paths.src + "/js/custom.js"
    ]
};

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src(js.jsSrc)
        .pipe(babel({presets: ['es2015']}) )
        .pipe(webpack())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .on('error', function (err) { gutil.log(gutil.colors.red('[Error]'), err.toString()); })
        .pipe(concat('bootstrap.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.minJs));
});

// Create watch task
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(paths.src + '/js/**/*.js', ['scripts']);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

So bootstrap 4 beta most probably uses ES6, and at the moment uglify() cannot minify ES6 code.

You will most probably need to use babel to convert ES6 to ES5 first then do the uglify.

ALSO I did some reading quick.
Try to debug your error even further by adding the following lines to you uglify output:

```
uglify().on('error', function(err) {
   gutil.log(gutil.colors.red('[Error]'), err.toString());
   this.emit('end');
})
```

This will print out  a more detailed error of you issues.

Comment: Is that not what `.pipe(babel({presets: ['es2015']}) )` should be doing?

Comment: Yes it should, but i think webpack should be done before babel is piped. because webpack fixes the modular issues first before transpilling happens.

Comment: @Meek please check the answer again. I added a more detailed invocation that you could try to debug the uglify issues you are experiencing.

Comment: `internal/streams/legacy.js:59
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
      ^
SyntaxError: H:/website/956b117e6f07bdf09f7d.js: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level (242:1)
  240 |         })(jQuery)
  241 |
> 242 |         export default Button
      |         ^

  243 |
  244 |
  245 | /***/ }),`

Comment: - and button.js if the first js file to be included. So which package is not working? Babel? gulp-webpack?

Comment: This might be a long shot, but move your `.pipe(concat('bootstrap.min.js'))` to be processed first (before your babel pipe). I don't think it will make a difference but maybe it does.

Comment: ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' \src\js\bootstrap.min.js

Answer (score 0):

Use [`uglify-es`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-es) and load it with the [gulp-uglify composer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify#using-a-different-uglifyjs):

```
var uglifyES6 = require('uglify-es');
var composer = require('gulp-uglify/composer');
var uglify = composer(uglifyES6, console);
```

Also, you may want to use [pump](https://github.com/terinjokes/gulp-uglify/blob/master/docs/why-use-pump/README.md#why-use-pump) for better/easier error handling.